# Using a colon after a single word

Tags: lists, colons

I write instructions for our assembly lines. Frequently, I need to call their attention to something that is not a step, but that they need to know. My usual way of doing this is to write, "Note: Do thus and so." This will be included with the steps, which are in a numbered list, although the note is indented and not numbered. Is my use of a colon here correct, or would another mark such as an em dash be more appropriate? Also, should the following word be upper- or lower-case? I would like to stagger them vertically, but I am limited on room.

Comment: Headlines, signs, warnings, instructions and the like do not have to follow the stricter rules that prose virtually demands. Even in prose, using capitals after colons is an old-fashioned rather than an incorrect practice. Here, they add impact.

Comment: The typical answer to questions like this is: check whether your employer/customer has a style guide that discusses this, and follow that.  If you can’t find a style guide, look at similar documents that your company uses and do whatever they do.

Comment: That is about what I would do, if the text formatter let me.

Comment: As the guys said, your suggestion is correct… but more importantly, how likely is that t be the only Question arising from the same situation?

What made you doubt *Note:…* was acceptable, please?

Comment: Are these instructions in a user guide - a 8.5"x11" 3-ring notebook format, or are they printed placards affixed adjacent to the machinery they reference?